# A word or phrase to represent "I don't want to be exposed"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word or phrase that can convey the meaning

> I am reluctant to be exposed to the public domain.

For example, I don't want my photo, profile to be exposed on the university site, Newsweek,  etc.

If someone takes a picture of me or interviews me, just by saying "I am xxx", the person should understand that I don't want to be exposed.

So what is the xxx?

Comment: Perhaps something like unveil or reveal? "I am reluctant to reveal to the public"

Comment: You are camera-shy. It gets the meaning across.

Comment: You're restricting your choices by supposing that the most appropriate term here should be a ***noun phrase***. To my mind, ***I value my privacy*** is probably the best bet, but that doesn't fit your request for a missing word in the context of ***I am xxx***.

Comment: What's wrong with reluctant? I don't think you mean exposed. I think you mean posted.

Comment: Outed? As in, "I don't want to be outed?" although that is usually used for aspects of identity/sexuality

Comment: If it's the 'public' rather than the 'exposed' part that counts, what's exactly wrong with 'I'm reluctant to be public' please?

Certainly, 'I'm not a public person' is far from rare.

'In public' means as much as 'in private' doesn't it?

'go private' might be unusual but the very frequency of  either 'go public' or 'stay private' should make it immediately acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

The most common construction is probably

> I'm a private person.

You could also go with

> I'm uncomfortable in the limelight.

Answer (score 1):

Formally:

> I'm a private person.

[Private](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/private) (MW, definition 3c)

> preferring to keep personal affairs to oneself, valuing privacy highly

A little more informally, and slightly self-deprecating:

> I'm publicity-shy.